# Minimal vscode with hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode
I want to start typing a page
By pressing a hotkey, all the mini-map, status bar, activity bar & ... disappear so that I can reach the programming correctly.
And with that hotkey I go back to the previous state
Do you know the plugin? Thankful
(Sorry for the bad English!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSC has a command: **View: Toggle Zen Mode**

Default key binding: `Ctrl+K Z`